# android evenly space out views

Tags: android, view

Hi i'm trying to create a league table in which i have several different views problem is the name of the club pushes the rest of the views over depending on the size of the name is there a way that i can align everything so it lines up and/or restrict the length of the name?

heres what i'm looking for

```
1 Name.. 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 Name.. 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
3 Name.. 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

heres what mine is doing

```
6 Name 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 Name 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
8 Name 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9 Name 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
10 Name 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 Name 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

heres my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" 
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TeamName"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Team Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
         android:gravity="left"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/played"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textColor="@color/blue" 
          android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/won"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textColor="@color/blue" 
          android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
         android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lost"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
         android:textColor="@color/blue"
          android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goalsFor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textColor="@color/blue"
          android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goalsAgainst"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
         android:textColor="@color/blue"
          android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/difference"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textColor="@color/blue"
          android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textColor="@color/blue"
          android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @DheereshSingh hi Dheeresh i have tried using a Linear layout its does the same. i think restricting the name length would do it just how i can restrict the length of the name

Comment: try answer below and increase the layout_weight of your name Textview as per your need I think that will work for you and it will restrict the length of the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this if can use linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TeamName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Team Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/played"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/won"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lost"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawn"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goalsFor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goalsAgainst"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/difference"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".13"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: just one thing when position goes into double figures it pushes those from 10 onwards on a fration is there anyway i can handle that

Comment: sorry not get "it pushes those from 10 onwards on a fration"

Comment: sorry my error. in the league table there are 20 teams so everything is aligned up to team number 9 but at team number 10 because it is in double figures it moves everything to the right a little bit. ill add an example to my code of what its doing

Comment: ohh sorry I understand it other way.   is the layout_weight of both rows are same?

Comment: as this should not happen if layout_weight  is set then it should not effect other element space please update for XML in ..

Comment: hi Dheeresh i have updated my xml to what i currently have done